# How do you select which simulator profile to use when running Instruments

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, instruments

I am trying to find a memory leak in an IOS app in Xcode, using Instruments.  When I start Instruments from Xcode by using "Profile", it runs the "IPad Retina" IOS Simulator.  I want to use the "iPad" simulator.  Is there a way to select which simulator Instruments uses?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Attach to process?" if no then try clicking on target drop down list. Then select Attached to process and select iPad simulator. Note that the simulator should be running while doing this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am away from the computer and will try this when I get back. I am wondering though if this will be able to access the symbols/addresses for the program if I don't start it from within xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution running on `Xcode 5.1.1.`

In [**Instruments**],

1. **Pause** the recording
2. **Traverse** down the following path: *Choose Target* > *Options*.
3. Under Simulator Configuration, you'll **find** the devices that you can
   choose from.

**PS**: A screen shot would be normally attached, but StackOverflow does not permit so until a sufficient Reputation was gained.